# CSS Sprites showing broken image icon over image, but hover still works

Tags: css, internet-explorer, image, hover, sprite

I can't figure this out..hopefully someone else can.

I have an image button .  The hover effect works fine.  However, I have the IE broken image icon over the button image.

Lookie here: [Funky Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pm8xX.png) [Funky Image Hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUAyo.png)

As you can see...they both work except for that annoying broken image.

Here's my CSS:

```
.donate-btn{
background: transparent url(/custom/img/donate-btn.png) no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
height:45px;
width:210px;
float:left;
}
.donate-btn:hover{
background: transparent url(/custom/img/donate-btn.png) no-repeat;
height:45px;
width:210px;
background-position: 0 -45px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simply means you are referencing a non-existent image in the `source` attribute.  You should consider using the actual `<button>` tag instead.  It just needs a few extra style attributes to remove borders and padding:

```
.donate-btn{
    background: transparent url(/custom/img/donate-btn.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:45px;
    width:210px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    float:left;
}

.donate-btn:hover{
    background-position: 0 -45px;
}
```

I also simplied your CSS by removing some unnecessary styling in the hover state.

```
<button class="donate-btn" type="submit"></button>
```

Comment: @cballou:  works great in IE (all versions) and FF, but not Safari (on mac or pc).  Thoughts?

Comment: You need to ensure you have `type="submit"` on your button or it will not act as a submit button.

Comment: nevermind :)  it works.  there was a jquery error in the form that prevented the CSs from loading and other stuff.  it works now.  funny, FF 3.x is more forgiving than IE and safari