# What is this icon on the top left of my image?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer

There is this icon that I do not know how to get rid of in Internet Explorer. Can someone explain how to get rid of it and what it is?

[image]

Comment: This means the image isn't actually loading. Your css is pulling all the weight.

Comment: Broken image icon - means that the browser was not able to load the image.

Comment: Above two comments are answers but posted as comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image itself isn't loading. If you could post your code we could provide more help.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the css:

```
background: transparent url(whatever) **0 0** no-repeat;
border: none;
padding: 0;
```

evidently this worked for [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1918820/css-sprites-showing-broken-image-icon-over-image-but-hover-still-works)

Answer (score 0):

get the mouse on it.right click on it and get image properties.see where it is from.and you can do this
go to tools / internet options / advanced / Reset
that button resets all configs